# Django admin list_display of different data types with null

Tags: python, html, django, django-admin, django-admin-actions

I know I explained the title poorly, look I have a simple chat app where users can send text/audio/video/image and for me to render those messages I have a method that checks the type of the message and renders it accordingly if it was text then i will set safe to False in my template, else I will display what the function will give me which is an HTML code

What I really want is: Admin panel giving me message text[:50] if it was text, if it was audio then i can have an audio preview for it, if it was image or video or file then it will give me the url.
Is there anyway to do so?

here are my files so you can get a better understanding of what I'm saying:

models.py:

```py
class Message(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    room = models.ForeignKey(Room, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    text = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    video = models.FileField(upload_to="chat/room/vid", blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to="chat/room/img", blank=True, null=True)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to="chat/room/file", blank=True, null=True)
    audio = models.FileField(upload_to="chat/room/aud", blank=True, null=True)

    is_read = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def content(self):
        if self.text:
            return self.text
        elif self.video:
            return f"""
            <video width="320" height="240" controls>
                        <source src="{self.video.url}" type="video/mp4">
                        <source src="{self.video.url}" type="video/mov">
                        <source src="{self.video.url}" type="video/wmv">
                        <source src="{self.video.url}" type="video/avi">
                        <source src="{self.video.url}" type="video/avchd">
                    Your browser does not support the video tag.
                    </video> 
            """
        elif self.image:
            return f'<img src="{self.image.url}" alt="">'
        elif self.file:
            return f'<p><a href="{self.file.url}" download><i class="fas fa-download"></i> {self.filename()}</a></p>'
        elif self.audio:
            return f"""
            <audio controls>
                        <source src="{self.audio.url}" type="audio/pcm">
                        <source src="{self.audio.url}" type="audio/wav">
                        <source src="{self.audio.url}" type="audio/aiff">
                            <source src="{self.audio.url}" type="audio/mp3">
                                <source src="{self.audio.url}" type="audio/aac">
                                <source src="{self.audio.url}" type="audio/ogg">
                                <source src="{self.audio.url}" type="audio/flac">
                                <source src="{self.audio.url}" type="audio/wma">
                    Your browser does not support the audio element.
                    </audio>
            """
        else:
            return self.text
```

And here is my HTML template:

```
{% for room_message in room_messages %}
    {% if room_message.text %}
    <p>{{ room_message.content }}</p>
    {% else %}
    {{ room_message.content|safe }}<br>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Now where is the problem? at my admin panel if there wasn't a text it will give me "-" for the message content

My admin.py:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Room, Area, Message


admin.site.register(Room)
admin.site.register(Area)
@admin.register(Message)
class MessageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    '''Admin View for Message'''

    list_display = ('user','room', 'user', 'is_read', 'text')
    readonly_fields = ('date',)
```

Comment: Looks like you've set `text` in `list_display` but not other fields for `video`, `audio` etc.
Can you try to include those and see what happens?

Comment: When I did so the admin page became very unclean, I have 4 columns beside each other where only one of them is used, I was trying to find a cleaner way, also the audio gives me a download link instead of playing it but the image and video are okay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to have a function called `get_content()` and include that in `list_display` like

```
list_display = ('user','room', 'user', 'is_read', 'get_content')
```

Have this function inside your class

```
def get_content(self, obj):
    if obj.text:
        return obj.text
    elif obj.video:
        return obj.video.url
    elif obj.image:
        return obj.image.url
    elif obj.file:
        return obj.file.url
    elif obj.audio:
        return obj.audio.url
```

This method must be inside your ModelAdmin class.

Comment: Not really but I will spend minuted debugging till I found how to fix it, the problem is that "self" doesn't take the message instant, it instead takes message.MessageAdmin instance. but thanks so much for your help

Comment: The only thing missing is to be able to get the "self", is there anyway to get the instance mesasge id and then do a filtiring to get it?